# webkitEnterFullscreen() using external button works in Chrome and Safari but not iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webkit, html5-video

Can anyone tell me why webkitEnterFullscreen() using an external button works in Chrome and Safari, but not iOS?

In iOS, the button doesn't work even if I set the video to "visible". It appears to only work once the video is playing, then it will allow me to launch fullscreen. I can't script it either by using "this.play();", it only works when a human hits the play button.

I'm using an iPad 2 and iOS 5.0.1

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fullscreen Video</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function(){
                // hide video
                $("#myVideo").css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'display' : 'none'});

                // extend button functionality
                $('#fs').bind('click', function() {
                    // display the video
                    $("#myVideo").css({'visibility' : 'visible'});

                    // launch the video fullscreen
                    $("#myVideo")[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Fullscreen Video</h1>
        <video id="myVideo" width="852" height="480" controls="false" preload="false">
            <source src="videos/myVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="fs" value="Fullscreen">

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you override the "`display: none`" when you override the "`visibility: hidden`"?

I position my video offscreen (-2000 with `position: absolute`), and I use:

```
<script>

var videoPlayFullscreen = function() {
       $('video').get(0).play();        
       $('video').get(0).webkitEnterFullscreen();  
    };

</script>
```

I couldn't get it to work until I used the "`.get(n)`" if that helps. (which may be the same as what you are doing:  `$('video')[n]`.

But my fullscreen only works if the video is already playing, like yours, but the code above to get it to play works on the iphone4, and iPad 1st gen.

My issue: On the iPad 1st gen, the video plays on first click (first time `videoPlayFullscreen` function is run) and goes into fullscreen on the second click (second time the function is run). I am thinking it is not ready to do the fullscreen right away, so maybe a delay time before that would work?

The play code works on the iPhone 4 (which initiates fullscreen with just a play and doesn't use/need the `webkitEnterFullscreen` in my experience).